# U-SQL with XmlExtractor - elements inside elements

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In U-SQL I am trying to get a list of elements inside elements, using the [XmlExtractor](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats). But I cannot get the nested collection.

It is a list of items, which has locations. With the [XmlExtractor](https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats/Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats) I can get a collection of elements, but I don't see how I can get a collection that contains a collection. An XML sample is shown below.

Any ideas?

```
<root>
<Item>
    <Header>
        <id>111</id>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <Station>k4</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Station>k5</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
        </Locations>
    </Body>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Header>
        <id>222</id>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <Station>k4</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Station>k5</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
        </Locations>
    </Body>
</Item>
</root>
```

Comment: Can you confirm what your expected results look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by making an extractor that takes the XML in one string, and then calls a method using xpath, returning an SQL.Array, where the string has comma separated values of of the result. The result looks like this:

```
111;k4,2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00
111;k5,2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00
222;k4,2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00
222;k5,2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00
```

The standard XmlExtractor cannot do this, and I also decided that it is better to postpone the parsing of the xml to after it has been extracted, because there can be multiple steps on the same xml.

Comment: Could you share your solution, plz? May be Github could be the right place. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database has powerful abilities to shred XML.  Maybe if this is already in your estate/architecture it might make a simple alternative to custom code?  A simple example:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root>
<Item>
    <Header>
        <id>111</id>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <Station>k4</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Station>k5</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
        </Locations>
    </Body>
</Item>
<Item>
    <Header>
        <id>222</id>
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <Locations>
            <Location>
                <Station>k4</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
            <Location>
                <Station>k5</Station>
                <Timestamp>2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00</Timestamp>
            </Location>
        </Locations>
    </Body>
</Item>
</root>'


/*
111;k4,2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00
111;k5,2017-08-30T02:04:18.2506945+02:00
222;k4,2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00
222;k5,2017-08-30T02:12:36.1218601+02:00
*/

SELECT 
    r.c.value('(Header/id/text())[1]', 'int' ) id,
    b.c.value('(Station/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)' ) station,
    b.c.value('(Timestamp/text())[1]', 'varchar(40)' ) [timestamp],
    b.c.value('(Timestamp/text())[1]', 'datetimeoffset' ) [timestamp2]
FROM @xml.nodes('root/Item') r(c)
    CROSS APPLY r.c.nodes('Body/Locations/Location') b(c)
```

You can do something similar if the XML is stored in a table also.

My results:
[image: My results]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that achieves the desired results using the extractors provided.

```
USE master;

REFERENCE SYSTEM ASSEMBLY [System.Xml]
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY master.[Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml]

@e = EXTRACT a string, b string
     FROM "CollectTest.xml"
     USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlDomExtractor(rowPath:"Item",
                             columnPaths:new SQL.MAP<string, string> { {"Header", "a"}, {"Body", "b"} });
@f = SELECT @e.a, t.c, t.d
     FROM @e
         CROSS APPLY new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Xml.XmlApplier("b","Location", new SQL.MAP<string,string> { {"Station", "c"}, {"Timestamp", "d"} })  AS t(c string, d string);


OUTPUT @f TO "foo.txt" USING  Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader:true);
OUTPUT @e TO "foo2.txt" USING  Outputters.Tsv(outputHeader:true);
```

The first rowset @e uses the XmlDomExtractor to create a row set containing "ID" in col a and the child XML code in col b.

The second rowset @f then uses XmlApplier to extract the values from the nested xml code and cross apply it to the correct rows. The sample xml was copied from the post above and saved in the USQLDataRoot folder as "CollectTest.xml."

- Note: Got lazy and the output for Header contains some unwanted node syntax but adding an intermediate xpath or XmlApplier step between @e and @f should solve this.